# Laravel / Mongodb - Trying to access array offset on value of type float

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am using laravel mongodb. I am trying to get **unique/distinct** `$product_field` and corresponding `id` key vlaue from all the documents of a single collection.

Here `$product_field` is contain the dynamic key name of the document for example: brand.

Also, I want to make a pagination. I am using this code:

```
$perPage = isset($data['per_page']) ? (int) $data['per_page'] : 10;
$pageNumber = isset($data['page']) ? (int) $data['page'] : 1;

$query = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('products_' . $id_project);

// Fetch all distinct values of the product_field along with the corresponding id
$distinctValues = $query->distinct($product_field, ['id'])->get();

// Convert the collection to an array
$distinctValues = $distinctValues->toArray();

// Count the total number of items
$totalItems = count($distinctValues);

// Calculate the total number of pages
$totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $perPage);

// Skip calculation
$skip = ($pageNumber - 1) * $perPage;

// Slice the data to fetch the paginated results
$paginatedData = array_slice($distinctValues, $skip, $perPage);

$data = [];

// Iterate over the paginated data and include 'id' and '$product_field' key values
foreach ($paginatedData as $item) {
    $id = (string) $item['id'];
    unset($item['id']); // Remove the 'id' key from the array
    $item['id'] = $id; // Add 'id' key value to the array
    $item['product_field'] = $product_field; // Add '$product_field' key value to the array
    $data[] = $item;
}

$pagination = [
    'total'         => $totalItems,
    'per_page'      => $perPage,
    'current_page'  => $pageNumber,
    'last_page'     => $totalPages,
    'from'          => $paginatedData ? $skip + 1 : null,
    'to'            => $paginatedData ? $skip + count($paginatedData) : null,
    'data'          => $data,
];
```

But I am getting this error message:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type float

at this line:

```
$id = (string) $item['id'];
```

can you tell me why and how to solve it ?

Comment: If this uses [distinct](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/distinct/) then the result will be the distinct values themselves `foreach ($paginatedData as $id)` should be enough

Comment: @apokryfos I don't get. basically I need both $product_field and corresponding 'id' key value